clang-format align assignment to nearest tab (no spaces)
I want to get code like this:
typedef struct FooStruct {
\t  u_int16_t bar;\t  /**< Blah */
\t  u_int16_t baz;\t  /**< Bleh */
} Foo;

(where I'm using \t   to indicate a 4-column wide tab character)
But I can't get clang-format to keep the comments aligned to the nearest tab character. I'm using the following .clang-format file, and using clang-format-12:
# Format Style Options, requires clang-format-12
# See https://releases.llvm.org/12.0.1/tools/clang/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html
---
BasedOnStyle: LLVM
AlignConsecutiveAssignments: AcrossComments
AlignConsecutiveMacros: AcrossEmptyLinesAndComments
AlignOperands: DontAlign
AlignTrailingComments: true
AllowAllArgumentsOnNextLine: false
AllowShortBlocksOnASingleLine: Never
AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine: None
AllowShortEnumsOnASingleLine: false
AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine: Never
AllowShortLoopsOnASingleLine: false
AllowShortCaseLabelsOnASingleLine: false
BreakBeforeBraces: Custom
BraceWrapping:
  AfterControlStatement: Always
  AfterUnion: false
  BeforeElse: true
  BeforeWhile: false
  AfterEnum: false
  AfterFunction: false
  AfterStruct: false
  SplitEmptyFunction: false
BreakBeforeTernaryOperators: true
ColumnLimit: 140
ExperimentalAutoDetectBinPacking: true
IncludeBlocks: Merge
IndentCaseLabels: true
IndentWidth: 4
PenaltyBreakAssignment: 21
PenaltyIndentedWhitespace: 0
ReflowComments: false
SortIncludes: false
TabWidth: 4
UseTab: Always
PointerAlignment: Right

And clang-format wants to put exactly one space after the ; and then align the comments to that:
typedef struct FooStruct {
\t  u_int16_t bar; /**< Blah */
\t  u_int16_t baz; /**< Bleh */
} Foo;

Is it possible to tell clang-format to align the trailing comments to the nearest tab-width, such that there are only \t characters between the final ; and the start of the comment?

Edit: please let's not start up the tabs-vs-spaces holy war. I've got a legacy codebase, it is what it is, I'm trying to automate the existing style guidelines, I'm not trying to bring mass reform to 100k lines of C code.

I guess everyone has their own style, but I generally would avoid using tabs for alignment as that tends to break horribly when people view code with different tab widths (as opposed to tabs for indentation, which is fine). It’s possible that clang-format doesn’t support this kind of formatting?

Note that the width of a tab, and whether "characters" is even a meaningful unit for measuring that, is a function of the means by which the code containing the tab is displayed.  There is no such thing as a "4-column wide tab character" except in the context of some particular layout technology and configuration.

@beyarkay, Good luck with your goal.  I'd recommend spaces and not '\t' as it is more profitable.  Yet such issues I do not find productive. I long ago gave up on using uncommon format schemes and let my IDE's auto-formatter handle it.  As with such style issues, I recommend to follow your group's coding standard.

the tabs-vs-spaces holy war is not gonna get solved here. I've got a legacy codebase with ✨style choices✨ (such as tabs for alignment) that I've gotta abide by, regardless of my preferences or your recommendations. I'm attempting to bring some automation to the company's style standard via clang-format, and hoping to not have a million-line-diff because of it
